# driving motor DC 24V with MOSFET

Tags: mosfet, motor

[image]
this is the basic shematic, i added a freewheel diode with the connector of the motor .

Im driving a DC motor 24DC 1A, im using PWM 500Hz from microcontroller and MOSFET IRF740 with a driver TLP250 and of course the freewheel diode in parallel with the motor.

the problem is that i don't have a clean zero state when the MOSFET is in conduction as you can see in the picture, and because of that he's overheating, but when im using a resistive load i have a very good commutation.

So the problem is because of the inductive load, what should i do to get rid of it ?
[image: signal between Drain and source]

Comment: Could you post a circuit and point out your probe location?

Comment: And (apart from posting that _complete_ schematic) what was your resistive load? (and why such a high voltage MOSFET, rather than a higher current one?)

Comment: The most obvious thing wrong is that your freewheel diode is not kicking in.

Comment: Furthermore, you're not showing your scope settings. Also, those noisy OFF state voltages are very peculiar. How about showing your gate voltages? And finally, SHOW YOUR SCHEMATIC!

Comment: You got a male MOSFET there... That's your problem.

Comment: @Asmyldof it was resistor 12Ohm, the voltage for the gate is 15v and i tried with 18v it is the same thing.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast i will try with another diode next time, and for the scope i already said that the frequency is 500Hz and supply 24*root(2)=34V and since the motor is 24DC i will limit this supply with the PWM.

Comment: @soosaisteven what do you mean by male MOSFET ?

Comment: Pwm frequency quite small, probably you get too high current. what is the load?

Comment: Because the poster said " HE is overheating",

Comment: You still haven't specified your scope vertical sensitivity.  Your root2 calculation makes no sense unless you are providing a 24 VAC power supply with rectifiers and caps. Is your power supply 24 VDC, or what? What is the peak voltage on your scope trace? And please post the gate drive waveform.

Comment: @GregoryKornblum the load is a DC motor maximum current 1A, Rdson=0.5ohm P= 0.5W so technically the MOSFET won't heat up. and for the PWM i will change it of course in the real application probably 4 or 5Khz

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast yes of course im using 24VAC with rectifiers and caps. and sorry i don't have yet the right to post more than 2 links that's why i didn't post the gate signal, but i check it and it doesn't problem i got rectangular signal with 15V and 0V.

Comment: @lawir, motor rated 1A doesn't necessarily draw just 1A. Think about it, it probably has resistance around 1-2Ohm, right? With Rdson together, if open for enough time, it can draw 10A easily. How much time? Depends on inductance. But just for your reference, normally pwm frequency should be 10kHz to even 50kHz.

Comment: Hope you have enough reputation now. Please, post whatever you need.

Comment: @GregoryKornblum thanks for your help i appreciate .

Comment: @GregoryKornblum i fed the motor with continue 24V and it didn't consume more than 0.8A. And for the frequency, tell me please based on what we choose it? i think if we go far in frequency we increase the losses due to commutation right?!

Comment: Frequency is usually selected so it takes several cycles to reach notor's time constant. As for motor current, alright, but remember that during startup the current is probably much higher, you just don't see it.

Comment: @GregoryKornblum thanks for your help, tomorow i have a meeting with my teacher i will let you know if we find the problem .

Comment: Ok. Measure ohmic resistance of the motor, just to have the whole picture. Also one important thing: remove that 100 ohm resistor from the gate. It's a kind of lame EMI protection... Real men don't have EMI issues on gate because they have good layout- short traces, return path... On the other hand the resistor is a common heat reason, although not on such low frequency.

Comment: @GregoryKornblum  you mean that the 100ohm resistor is for EMI protection ?

Comment: Yes. Usually they put a resistor there to limit the current and this way to reduce emission. But it's not good, because limited current can't charge the gate quickly, killing all advantages of switching system and heating up the MOSFET

Comment: @GregoryKornblum "limited current can't charge the gate quickly" ,i know but that's why we put a low value resistor. this resistor is recommended by the manufactor.

Comment: Just remember that, ok?

Comment: @GregoryKornblum ok. but i didn't know about it, why is this resistor is a protection for EMI ?

Comment: I just wrote: it limits current. High current pulses potentially emit emi.

Comment: @GregoryKornblum ah ok thanks. i found the solution to the problem but i haven't find the answer why. the problem was because of the frequency, i tried with 32khz and it worked just fine, good zero state and without overheating in the MOSFET

Comment: if we increase the frequency we decrease the ondulation of current, so maybe the ondulation of current are the cause of this but why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Haha!

Nice, glad it help. So let's summarize.

1. The PWM frequency should be calculated according to motor time constant (L/R). You didn't measure ohmic resistance, so my educated guess is that it's around 5 ohms.

Wht happens when PWM frequency is low? Motor current reaches very high value despite your duty cycle.

I would argue that 32khz is a little high- high end servo work with such frequency. But it's definitely better than 0.5khz.

Now, i still hate your serial gate resistor. Why? Because it makes rise time of your MOSFET longer. During that time the voltage across transistor is not zero (average of half VBUS) and current is full, so power is quite high.